# SQL Error - Invalid Object Name Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I implement and support a software applicatoin that allows me to create macros within the application.  One of the macro steps is to execute a SQL procedure.  When I attempt to run a macro that is executing a stored proc (_*TSi*_CustomerAccountCorrection) I'm seeing this error:

```
Error 0 executing [__TSi__CustomerAccountCorrection].
Invalid object name 'TSI_ProService.dbo.Customer'.
```

If I run this stored proc in SQL Query Analyzer (SQL 2000 using Integrated Security), the proc runs just fine.  The application I'm running it through uses a SQL connection string that is set to use integrated security and I'm logged on as the same exact user as well.

Unfortunately, I do not have the source code for the application.  I was hoping that someone might recognize what is going on here or at least give me a suggestion as to what the issue might be.

As far as I can see, when running the stored proc through the application and through the query analyzer is exactly the same.

Here is the stored proc:

```
CREATE  PROCEDURE [dbo].[__TSi__CustomerAccountCorrection] AS
set xact_abort on
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ 
BEGIN TRANSACTION trans1
DECLARE cur_cust CURSOR FOR
 SELECT [AccountNumber] FROM DBSTR1.HQ.dbo.PSD_CustomerExport
DECLARE @accountNumber varchar(50);
DECLARE @custAccountNumber varchar(50);
DECLARE @query varchar(500);
OPEN cur_cust;

FETCH NEXT FROM cur_cust INTO @accountNumber;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN
 set @custAccountNumber = (SELECT TOP 1 [Account] FROM [Customer] WHERE [UserData2] = @accountNumber)

 if @custAccountNumber is null
 begin
  SET @custAccountNumber = @accountNumber
 end

 --UPDATE DBSTR1.HQ.dbo.PSD_CustomerExport SET [VcrAccountNumber] = @custAccountNumber WHERE [AccountNumber] = @accountNumber
 UPDATE DBSTR1.HQ.dbo.PSD_CustomerExport SET [VcrAccountNumber] = @custAccountNumber WHERE CURRENT OF cur_cust

 FETCH NEXT FROM cur_cust INTO @accountNumber;
END
CLOSE cur_cust;
DEALLOCATE cur_cust;
COMMIT TRANSACTION trans1
GO
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You sure it's running on the same user ? Feels like a default sql schema error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not executing in the same DB context when you run it remotely vs. when you run it in SSMS.

Notice that the `customer` table is not using the three part name.  SQL Server is making assumptions about the Database and schema that the `customer` table is in and is guessing wrong.

It is using whatever the default context is for the connection, which from your error code is likely the database `TSI_ProService` and the schema defaults to `dbo`.  One or both of these are incorrect for that table.

What DB and schema are that table in?  Use the 3PN (`Database.schema.object`) in the call in the proc and I think it will probably work fine.

Comment: What I don't understand is that the table is TSIPro_Service.dbo.Customer... By the way I typed the error incorrectly the error was TSIPro_Service not "TSI_ProService"

Comment: @user - It doesn't matter what DB it's in if that DB is not the default for the connection you are initializing for the remote call.

Comment: I'm a little slow... so are you telling me that I should replace "Customer" with "TSIPro_Service.dbo.Customer"?

Comment: Yes.  It's generally ALWAYS a good idea in procedures/views/scripts to fully qualify you object names unless you have a good reason NOT to.

Comment: Oh ok... thanks for the advice and the tip!  Unfortunately, I do not have my customers laptop right now so I cannot check this until later and I can try it out... I'll let you know and thanks again for everything!